# Function type A => C is not a subtype of B => C, although A implements B

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a customizable wrapper for alert dialogs in **Flutter** and have come across a really weird type problem:

There is a property called `iconSelector` which is defined as follows:

```
class EntitySelectionDialogFormField<E extends NamedEntity> extends DialogFormField<E> {
  final Icon Function(E)? iconSelector;
```

When I assign a function of the type `(TagCategoryData) => Icon` to it, this line throws the following error:

```
if (_formField.iconSelector == null) {
```

> type '(TagCategoryData) => Icon' is not a subtype of type '(NamedEntity) => Icon'

The `TagCategoryData` class definitely implements `NamedEntity`:

```
abstract class NamedEntity {
  String get name;
}

abstract class DataClassWithEntityName extends NamedEntity with OrderingName {}

class TagCategoryData implements DataClassWithEntityName {
  // (...)
}
```

I checked if the nullability of the property is the root of the problem, but it isn't. (Obviously, the null check is gone, but the same error will occur in the next line that calls the function.)

How is it even possible that I assign a `(TagCategoryData) => Icon` function to a `((NamedEntity) => Icon)?` property if they are incompatible, and I will only get an error when I first access it? Shouldn't I receive an error on the constructor call that assigns the value?

---

**UPDATE**

I think I found the issue. I have a class called `DialogForm` that creates all configured fields of the dialog form. The list of form fields is of type `List<DialogFormField>` and `EntitySelectionDialogFormField` inherits from `DialogFormField`. The corresponding widget for `EntitySelectionDialogFormField` is called `EntitySelector` and has a generic argument `E extends NamedEntity`.

The following code does ***not*** cause a compiler error, although `EntitySelector` is instantiated without a generic parameter:

```
if (formField is TextDialogFormField) {
  return _buildTextInput(context, formField);
} else if (formField is EntitySelectionDialogFormField) {
  return EntitySelector(formField,
    updateFormState: (value) => _updateValue(formField.identifier, value));
}
```

`EntitySelectorState` has the property `EntitySelectionDialogFormField<E> _formField;`. It is also the class with the line that throws the error:

`if (_formField.iconSelector == null) {`

So the actual issue is that `_formField` is of type `EntitySelectionDialogFormField<NamedEntity>` when it should be `EntitySelectionDialogFormField<TagCategoryData>`.

I managed to make the code work with this hack:

```
} else if (formField is EntitySelectionDialogFormField) {
  // TODO The NamedEntity is not necessarily TagCategoryData here
  return EntitySelector<TagCategoryData>(formField as EntitySelectionDialogFormField<TagCategoryData>,
      updateFormState: (value) => _updateValue(formField.identifier, value));
}
```

However, I would like to get the generic parameter of `formField`'s type and pass that to `EntitySelector`.

Comment: How do you instantiate the `EntitySelectionDialogFormField`?  It sounds like you aren't specifying that it should be a `EntitySelectionDialogFormField<TagCategoryData>`, in which case it will default to being a `EntitySelectionDialogFormField<NamedEntity>` if it can't be inferred.

Comment: Also, an `Icon Function(TagCategoryData)` is not substitutable for an `Icon Function(NamedEntity)`.  The latter is a function that can take *any* `NamedEntity`, not just the narrower `TagCategoryData` type.  I'm not sure why it sounds like you're getting a runtime error instead of a compile-time one.  If none of this helps you, please provide a minimal example that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: See [substituting types](https://dart.dev/language/type-system#substituting-types)

Comment: @jamesdlin `EntitySelectionDialogFormField` is instantiated in a factory class, and the method that creates the dialog is called via `dialogFactory.getSelectEntityDialog<TagCategoryData>`. I also double-checked that the generic variables in my constructor and method calls are consistent.

Comment: @jamesdlin Obviously, you cannot assign a function of the type `Icon Function(NamedEntity)` to a variable of the type `Icon Function(TagCategoryData)`, but it should work the other way around, shouldn't it? And yes, I also feel like I should get a compile-time error if there was a clear type mismatch, but I don't.

Comment: I found the error and updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the updated original post, the issue was that the classes for dialog widget configuration (`DialogFormField`) and instantiation (e.g. `EntitySelector`) did not know about each other and I did not pass on the generic type from the configuration to the widget.

As it appears, it is not easy / not possible to retrieve the type of a generic parameter in a type, like this:

```
// DOES NOT WORK!!
} else if (formField is EntitySelectionDialogFormField<anyType>) {
  print(anyType);
```

Neither is it possible to pass a runtime type obtained from one of `formField`'s properties as a generic parameter:

```
  // DOES NOT WORK!!
  return EntitySelector<formField.inititalValue.runtimeType>(formField,
      updateFormState: (value) => _updateValue(formField.identifier, value));
}
```

I solved the issue by moving the widget instantiation to the `DialogFormField` class, where I can just pass on the generic parameter:

```
abstract class DialogFormField<T> {
  final String identifier;
  final T initialValue;
  Widget buildWidget(Function(String fieldId, T newValue) formUpdateCallback);

  const DialogFormField(this.identifier, {required this.initialValue});
}

class EntitySelectionDialogFormField<E extends NamedEntity> extends DialogFormField<E> {

  // (...)

  @override
  Widget buildWidget(Function(String fieldId, E newValue) formUpdateCallback) {
    return EntitySelector<E>(this, updateFormState: (E newValue) => formUpdateCallback(this.identifier, newValue));
  }
}
```